# Using Export to save show

Tags: export

How can I save a graph which is shown by "Show" in svg format? I tried below code but it doesnt save anything:

```
Export["test.svg", 
 Show[ss, aa4, a4, dd, linee, topp, bot, bothobothh, dtd, coli, ta, 
  dtd, sepp, bachs, ba1, b1, te, mox, bach1, pol1, point, ero, mox2, 
  moxx, xaxx, yaxx, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {Style["Subscript[\[CapitalGamma],r]", Purple, 
     FontFamily -> "Zapfino", FontSize -> 24], 
    Style[x^2, Orange, FontFamily -> "Zapfino", FontSize -> 24]},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Large, Black]]]
```

Comment: Did you get the chance to look at the result of `Show` separately? i.e. before exporting it? Does it show anything?  was there an error from `Show`? Are you sure you are looking for `test.svg` in the correct Folder? DId you do `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];` before? If not, it will not be saved in same folder as the notebook. It will go to your home folder which depends on the OS where that is.

Comment: Yes, show works outside of the Export @Nasser

Comment: oh, I did find it in another folder. Thank you. But now, there is another problem: texts are badly set in the output @Nasser